# Regexp для получения Html Tag Node

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Например из строки `<span class="example">` получить просто **span** (любой тег Html)

Comment: Чем закончились ваши попытки?

Comment: Успехом, `preg_replace('/\<([\w]+)\s.*\>/ismU','$1', '<span class="example">')`
Может есть вариант чуть лучше?

Comment: Конечно есть, тот же domDocument

Comment: знаю, есть такие и на php (phpQuery), но мне не нужно парсить всю страничку, это частная ф-ция, которая будет работать только с таким типом строки

Answer (score 0):

Если требуется найти теги, при этом избежать повторов, то можно написать регулярное выражение, а полученный массив обработать функцией для удаления повторов. Выглядеть будет так:

```
$str = '<div style="position: relative; width: 200px; height: 100px"> 
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 200px"> 
        <img width="180" height="50" src="http://www.google.com.ua/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" /> 
    </div> 
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 8%; left: 20%; width: 250px; text-decoration-style: dotted; color: #9d0000"> 
        Текст из файла 
    </div> 
</div>
Текст
<span class="example">';

var_dump(get_tags($str));

function get_tags($str) {
    preg_match_all('~<(?<tags>[a-z]+)[^>]*>~', $str, $a);
    return (isset($a) ? array_unique($a['tags']) : $str);
}
```

Результат:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => div
  2 => img
  4 => span
```

Так же можно построить шаблон с помощью ретроспективной и опережающей позитивных проверок - таким образом в результирующем массиве будет меньше *"лишних"* соответствий. Например:

```
preg_match_all('~(?<=<)[a-z]+(?=[^>]*\s*/?>)~', $str, $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => div
            [1] => div
            [2] => img
            [3] => div
            [4] => span
        )
)
```

UPD: Ну или так:

```
preg_match('~(?<=<)[a-z]+(?=[^>]*\s*/?>)~', $str, $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: @rodigy вполне вероятно, что под какие-то теги нужно будет поправить шаблон.

Comment: что в этом патерне значит <tags>?

Comment: @rodigy это именованная подмаска - в результирующий массив $a будет добавлен ключ 'tags', при обращении к которому **$a['tags']** вы получите интересующий вас набор значений

Comment: хорошее решение, может пригодиться, но в рамках данной задачи немного излишне

Comment: @rodigy я так понял, что под избыточностью вы подразумевали набор данных в результирующем массиве, и с учётом этого подправил свой ответ.

Comment: Под избыточностью я подразумевал, что в искомой строке будет всегда 1 тег, но даже в таком виде вполне применимо

Comment: @rodigy так тогда ещё проще - вам не нужен глобальный поиск в строке.

Answer (score 0):

Зачем с html работать регулярками, если есть [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Можно пример? Эта строка не является валидным дом элементом